# Loop through array of arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array of arrays formatted like the following:

```
$list = [ ["fdsa","1","fdsa"],["sadf","0","asdf"],["frfrf","0","sadfdsf"] ]
```

How can I loop through every single value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alphabetize array of arrays PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391474/alphabetize-array-of-arrays-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator)?

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($list)) as $item){
        var_dump($item);
}

string(4) "fdsa"
string(1) "1"
string(4) "fdsa"
string(4) "sadf"
string(1) "0"
string(4) "asdf"
string(5) "frfrf"
string(1) "0"
string(7) "sadfdsf"
```

... unless you want it more structured...

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$array = array(array("!","Hello","World"));
foreach($array as $key){
    $myvar = $key[0];
    $myvar2 = $key[1];
    $myvar3 = $key[2];
}
```

UPDATED!

Hope it helped!

Comment: And what do you do if there's an array in an array in an array? Add another loop? Or will you then start looking at recursive functions?