# Alphabetize array of arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I have an array of arrays formatted like the following:

```
$list = [ ["fdsa","1","fdsa"],["sadf","0","asdf"],["frfrf","0","sadfdsf"] ]
```

How can I alphabetize `$list` based on the first value of every inner array?

Thanks!

Comment: You will find what you need here... http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: http://imgur.com/GXkQloT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

asort($list);
// OR
array_multisort($list);

?>
```

PHP Manual: [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.asort.php) and [`array_multisort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 2):

I had this function for another answer but it can be modded to do the same:

```
// This sorts simply by alphabetic order
function reindex( $a, $b )
{
    // Here we grab the values of the 'code' keys from within the array.
    $val1 = $a[0];
    $val2 = $b[0];

    // Compare string alphabetically
    if( $val1 > $val2 ) {
        return 1;
    } elseif( $val1 < $val2 ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Call it like this:
usort( $array, 'reindex' );

print_r( $array );
```

Original: [Sorting multidimensional array based on the order of plain array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306741/sorting-multidimensional-array-based-on-the-order-of-plain-array/19307136#19307136)

Comment: http://imgur.com/GXkQloT

Comment: Or: `function reindex($a,$b){ return strcmp($a[0],$b[0]);}` (which does the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

```
function order($a, $b){
     if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }

$list = [ ["fdsa","1","fdsa"],["sadf","0","asdf"],["frfrf","0","sadfdsf"] ];

    usort($list, "order");


    var_dump($list); die;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
asort($list);
```

This will simply do the job for you.

Also see: http://php.net/manual/de/function.asort.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to sort using your own comparison function and use it along with `usort()`.